# Rails remote form with param

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, sweetalert

I currently have a form

```
<%= form_for @emailer, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %>
  <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

which I'm also calling from a [JS popup](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2)

```
const {value: email} = await Swal.fire({
  input: 'email',
  .
  .
  .
})
if (email) {
  form = $("#new_emailer")[0]
  Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
}
```

It is working, but of course the form is not receiving any email, so the new `emailer` is not created.

How can I submit the form by also sending the value of the email field inside the popup?
Like

```
Rails.fire(form, email, 'submit');
```

**EDIT WITH POSSIBLE SOLUTION:**
I actually tried

```
if (email) {
  form = $("#new_emailer")[0]
  $('#emailer_email').val(email) // this is the email field of the form
  Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
}
```

and it is working fine, but I'm not sure that's the best solution.

Comment: I see no element with id `subscriber_email` on your code. Also, could it be that there's more than one element with id 'new_emailer` when you try to frie the submit event? `Rails.fire(form, 'submit')` should indeed send the form with the email if the email field has a value (which looks like you are setting it but the ID confuses me).

Comment: @arieljuod sorry, just edited. That code is working and sending the form with the right email. But I would like to know if there's any other way of doing it instead of manually "hacking" the email field. Somethink like `Rails.fire(form, email_value, 'submit');`

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is not rails' remote form but that js popup plugin. I think you are asking the user the email with the popup but you are showing a now field that's not the actual form's email field so you have to set the actual form field manually after. But I understand that's how the plugin works, it let's you ask for a value but it only returns the value and you have to set it where it goes. I don't think there's a simpler way to do that, `fire` is a generic method to trigger events on elements, not something specific for forms so there's no special syntax for params.

Comment: One thing you could try is to use the "form" attribute on the popup's email field if you have that control, but I'm not sure the field is still on the DOM when the fire method is called since the popup could be gone, I wouldn't use this option, it could save you some lines, but setting the value manually is more error proof.